# Angular 16, load a javascript module into index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-modules

Consider a simple "module" such as:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert("I am doing something");
}

export { doSomething };
```

Say it is in a file called `doSomething.js` (or `doSomething.mjs` if you prefer) and this file name has been entered in the `script` array in `angular.json`.

In the `<head>` section of index.html you have

```
<script type="module">
    import { doSomething } from "/doSomething.js"; // or /.mjs
    doSomething();
</script>
```

If doSomething.js were a plain javascript file, (with no `export` statement), all would be fine, but angular throws an error when encountering the `export` statement, so you can't really use modules (like this), especially not if they are going to import additional modules. Using .mjs instead of .js makes no difference -- angular wants plain js, not a module. What am I missing? How does one load a module here?

Comment: Do you need to add it to the scripts array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Angular application, importing and using ES modules directly in the `index.html` file is not supported. Angular uses its own build system and module loader to bundle and load JavaScript modules within the context of the Angular application.

To use your `doSomething.js` module in an Angular application, you should follow the Angular module system and import the module within your Angular components or services instead of directly in the `index.html` file. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a TypeScript module:

   - Create a new TypeScript module file, let's say `do-something.ts`, in your Angular project.
   - Place your `doSomething` function inside this module file.
   - Export the `doSomething` function as part of the module.
   - Example:

     ```js
     export function doSomething() {
       alert("I am doing something");
     }
     ```
2. Import the module in a component or service:

   - Identify a component or service where you want to use the `doSomething` function.
   - Import the `doSomething` function from the `do-something` module file.
   - Example:

     ```js
     import { doSomething } from './do-something';

     // Use the doSomething function in your component or service
     doSomething();
     ```
3. Use the component or service in your application:

   - Include the component in your Angular application's template or use the service in your application logic.
   - Angular will handle the module resolution and bundling during the build process.

By following this approach, your modules will be properly bundled and managed within the Angular application. The module system provided by Angular enables better code organization, dependency management, and allows you to take advantage of TypeScript features.

It's important to note that importing modules directly in the `index.html` file is not the recommended approach in Angular applications. The `index.html` file is mainly used as the entry point for the Angular application, and the module loading and code execution should happen within the Angular context using Angular components, services, and modules.

Comment: Looks like a chatGPT answer.

Comment: I figured that since this particular set of functionality is needed everywhere in the app, it should be in index.html. Thank you for clarifying that this is not the case. I can certainly import it in each of the many places it is needed, even though that sees a bit unfortunate. So too then with something like axios? -- don't <script> it into index.html, but import it repeatedly where needed?

Comment: In a related question, in reality "doSomething" is part of a set of related modules. A few of them have cross-dependencies. For example, one provides a layer on top of axios, and another one uses that layer to log issues from the front end to the back end. Will relative path imports be followed in Angular, for example, 'import blah from "../ajax/myAjax.js"'? I have the impression that *all* imports seen by Angular are meant to be full path URLs relative the the website. If I do that, the imports won't work in Node.

Answer (score 1):

I get it to work this way:

(1) Remove the module entry from `angular.json`;

(2) Add `doSomething.js` to `assets` folder to make it available;

(3) Include the module to `index.html` file within `head` tag

```html
<script type="module" src="/assets/doSomething.js">
</script>

<script type="module">
  import { doSomething } from "/doSomething.js";
  doSomething();
</script>
```

Now the alert are shown and no error are thrown on console.

*ps.: Tested on Angular 15*

Answer (score 0):

Any file to be included to your angular project, should be done via "/assets/" folder, not only scripts, even normal documents, images, videos, libraries like bootstrap, font-awesome can be accessed from there.